# Improve song recommendation model with previous recommendations or new songs?

Tags: modeling, random-forest

I have a random forest music recommendation model that has users rate songs, then returns songs that have the highest probability of the user liking them. Afterwards, I want to give the user the option to improve the recommendations of the model by rating more songs. Should they be asked to rate the songs that the model has already recommended, or totally random new songs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused on how rating a totally random new song would improve your model. If you want insight on how well your model performed, you need the user to rate the songs that it predicted.